# Bash: Output result of function into Sed parameters

Tags: bash, curl, sed

```
sed -i '$a\curl -s http://whatismyip.org/' file
```

Trying to find a way to pull the WAN IP and insert it into the last line of a file as illustrated above (not working of course). This will be utilized via command line.

```
sed -i '$a\test' file
```

This will insert "test" after the last line in "file" as utlilized but how could I output the result of a function or command in it's place within Sed's syntax? Any suggests (awk, perl, bash script?) are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` isn't required here. Just use this:

```
curl -s http://whatsmyip.org >> your.file
```

Note that bash supports the `>>` redirection operator which appends a program's output to a file

Comment: nice to see it helped you

Answer (score 3):

hek2mgl has shown you how to solve this specific problem. To address the more general question, you can do:

```
var=$(some command line)
```

This sets the shell variable `$var` to the output of the command. Then you can subsitute this into sed with:

```
sed -i "\$a\\$var" file
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Just for clarification does ``\\`` escape text input so a variable can be called within Sed parameters?
Example: 
``read -e -p "login: " -i $NewUser
sed -i -e 's|Username = "username"|Username = "$NewUser"|g' loginfile.foo``

Comment: `\\ ` is an escaped slash, so that the slash doesn't escape the `$` after it, which allows the shell to expand the variable inside the `sed` parameter.